# Installed Ruby 2.4 but when I'm still showing Ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to intsall Ruby 2.4 on my Mac Sierra machine.  I thought i had done it successfully ...

```
localhost:myproject nataliab$ rvm use 2.4.0
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.0'.
ruby-2.4.0 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.4.0'
localhost:myproject nataliab$ rvm install ruby-2.4.0
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.0'.
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.28.0', you are using older version '1.26.11'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.4.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Updating certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem'.
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is set, this might interact with the compilation and ruby.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/nataliab/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.4.0 - #downloading ruby-2.4.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11.9M  100 11.9M    0     0  2715k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 2880k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.4.0 - #extracting ruby-2.4.0 to /Users/nataliab/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.0....
ruby-2.4.0 - #configuring..................................................................
ruby-2.4.0 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.4.0 - #compiling.............................................................
ruby-2.4.0 - #installing.......
ruby-2.4.0 - #making binaries executable..
Installed rubygems 2.6.8 is newer than 2.4.8 provided with installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force  installation.
ruby-2.4.0 - #gemset created /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global
ruby-2.4.0 - #importing gemset /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems...............................................
ruby-2.4.0 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.4.0 - #gemset created /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0
ruby-2.4.0 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.4.0 - #generating default wrappers........
ruby-2.4.0 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.4.0 - #complete 
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
```

And then I see the right Ruby version ...

```
localhost:myproject nataliab$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

But when I open up a new terminal window, navigate to my project directory, I no longer see the newly installed version ...

```
localhost:myproject nataliab$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

How do I make my version stick?

Comment: Is the file `~/.ruby-version` or exists in the home directory? Or maybe in the project directory? The ruby version also can be in the Gemfile of the project.

Comment: Yeah I thinik putting it in the Gemfile would be more foolproof.  HOw do I do that?

Comment: just add `ruby "2.4.0"` to the Gemfile.

Comment: I added this and then started my Rails server and got the erorr, "Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0".

Comment: Place the file `.ruby-version` to the project directory with `2.4.0` and check again.

Comment: Am I also supposed to remove the "ruby '2.4.0'" declaration from the Gemfile?  Anyway, I did, and then created a file called ".ruby-version" at the root of my project directory with the line "2.4.0" (without quotes), but when I fire up "rails console", the prompt is "2.3.0 :001 >", so I don't hink it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your default *ruby*:

```
$ rvm default ruby-2.4.0
$ rvm list

#rvm rubies

#   ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
#=* ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
#   ruby-head [ x86_64 ]

## => - current
## =* - current && default
##  * - default
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I ran that command, got this response, "Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.0'." and then when i opened a new shell and ran "ruby -v" I got "ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16]".

Comment: I need to complete the installation with `rvm use 2.4` to switch to the new binary.

Answer (score 0):

In project dir

- do not add any 'ruby "2.4.0"' line in Gemfile
- if there is .rvmrc file delete it
- create files (at least some rvm versions require both version and gemset files to exist)

.ruby-version

`2.4.0`

.ruby-gemset

`app`

Trigger rvm to reload them

`cd .
ruby --version
rvm gemset list`

- install bundler for 2.4.0 (if it is missing)

  `rvm 2.4.0@global do gem install bundler`